# Include all weights from a Google Font Family

Tags: fonts

I know you can specify which font weights are included for a family,
but is there a way to include all font weights without having to specify them.
So let's say for example: 
Adding Raleway font to my page,
is it possible to have all of the 18 styles offered from this font without specifying in detail in the query string.

I know performance is/can be an issue.

Thanks

Comment: What use would that be? If you don't know which weights the font supports, you have *no idea* what happens when you use a weight value in your CSS that the font doesn't actually support (plenty of fonts on Google fonts that support less than the maximum 9 weights). Importing with an explicit list of weights means you (and anyone you work with, or anyone who inherits your CSS, including you 3 months from now) will know what they can use in the actual site CSS.

Comment: This would be useful for testing purposes, to experiment quickly with different weights. Later I could trim the list.